# How do I get updates of a wiki to my email?

Tags: wiki

I want to know if there are web applications or programs that can detect when a change is done to a wiki. Can the program inform you by email if the wiki has been changed.

Any help appreciated,
Ted.

Comment: We need to know which wiki software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

[ChangeDetection](http://www.changedetection.com/) should do what you need.